# How to attach subscriber to State or Binding in SwiftUI/Combine?

Tags: swift, binding, state, combine, publisher

With a Combine `Publisher`, I can use the following to call a closure whenever a value changes:

```
let cancellable = x.sink { value in … }
```

How can I achieve the same behaviour with a variable marked `@State` or `@Binding`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I was under the false impression that willSet/didSet do not work on property wrappers. If you make your comment into an answer, I will gladly accept!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that? Who would subscribe to that if you could achieve that

Comment: @NewDev Being able to subscribe to a State variable allows for both View code and non-View code to receive updates on the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

The below answer doesn't seem to work anymore, instead one can use `.onChange(of:)` instead on the property

```
.onChange(of: someProperty) { value in
    //use new value for someProperty
 }
```

---

You can use `willSet` and `didSet` as with any normal property

```
@State private var someProperty: String {
    didSet {

    }

    willSet {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not called for some reason. I'm using Picker and binding of @State variable.

Comment: @atereshkov Yes this seems to have changed, you should look into using `.onChange(of:  perform)`instead

Comment: `.onChange(of: myPropertyName) { newValue in 
}`
should be used on particular view instead of 
`didSet { }` on particular property in SwiftUI